# Find the sum of values in rows of one column for where the other column has NAN in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, nan

I have a dataframe with columns A and B. Column A has non continuous data where some of the rows are NAN and B has continuous data. I would like to create a third column where for each set of A rows with NAN it will have the sum of values in those same rows in B + the next valid value in B.
All other values in C should be NAN for NAN in A AND  the value of B for rows following a valid number in A.
Example:

```
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, None, None, 2, 5, None, None,3 ,4, 3, None , 5],
    'B': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130]}
```

Everything works fine except for the rows where I need the sum of B + next valid value in B.
I use the following code. I have this code but is seems it's a mess by now.

```
`result = df.groupby(df['A'].isnull().cumsum())['B'].sum().reset_index()
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'C': result['Pumped']})
df_result.loc[1:, 'C'] -= result.loc[0, 'Pumped']

df.loc[~mask, 'C'] = df.loc[~mask, 'Pumped']

valid_rows_after_nan = df['dWL'].notnull() & mask.shift(1).fillna(False)


df.loc[valid_rows_after_nan, 'C'] = df_result

print(df)`
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
`data = {
    'A': [1,  1, None, None, 2, 5, None, None,3 ,4, 3, None , 5],
    'B': [10, 20, 30,  40,  50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130],
    'C': [10, 20, None, None, 120, 60, None, None, 240, 100, 110, None, 5]
}
```

Comment: why do you have a 5 in the last row? I'd expect a 250

Comment: Sorry you are right it should be 250

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple version using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
# identify the non-NA and reverse
m = df.loc[::-1, 'A'].notna()

# group the preceding NA, sum, mask where NA
df['C'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum())['B'].transform('sum').where(m)
```

Output:

```
      A    B      C
0   1.0   10   10.0
1   1.0   20   20.0
2   NaN   30    NaN
3   NaN   40    NaN
4   2.0   50  120.0
5   5.0   60   60.0
6   NaN   70    NaN
7   NaN   80    NaN
8   3.0   90  240.0
9   4.0  100  100.0
10  3.0  110  110.0
11  NaN  120    NaN
12  5.0  130  250.0
```